# Vector3.MoveTowards while also following cursor?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm making a character that follows my mouse position.

I also have enemies that are being instantiated and would like that character to move towards the location of the enemy but be a few feet higher than the enemy.

Since my character is a flying enemy I'm unsure how to use move towards in unity. 
When my enemies are destroyed I would also like the character to continue following the cursor.

```c#
public class FollowCursor : MonoBehaviour 
{

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start ()
    {   
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () 
    {
        if(GameObject.FindWithTag("Enemy"))
        {   
            transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards.GameObject.FindWithTag("Enemy").transform.position;
        }
        else
        {   
            transform.position = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint( new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x,Input.mousePosition.y,8.75f));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I understand you wish to move towards a flying enemy and/or have the flying enemy move towards your character.

I also understand that you wish to use the MoveTowards method to do this.

You should be able to do this by ignoring the Y position or setting it to a fixed value.

Like this.

```c#
//Method used: Vector3 MoveTowards(Vector3 current, Vector3 target, float maxDistanceDelta); 

//Set movespeed/steps
float speed = 5f;
float step = speed * Time.deltaTime;

//Define y position
float yourFixedYValue = 8.75f;

//Find target
Vector3 enemyPosition = GameObject.FindWithTag("Enemy").transform.position;
Vector3 target = new Vector3(enemyPosition.x, yourFixedYValue, enemyPosition.z);

//Move from current position towards target with step increment.
transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, target, step);
```

Please elaborate what you mean if this didn't answer your question.

EDIT:

To move towards the mouse you could use a Raycast something like this inside your Update method.

```c#
if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) 
{ //If left mouse clicked
    RaycastHit hit; 
    Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition); //Fire ray towards where mouse is clicked, from camera.
    if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))  //If hit something
        target = hit.point; //point is a vector3 //hit.point becomes your target
}
```

That "something" can be any collider, also an enemy one. So can be used to move around in general and to move towards enemies.